# Can't mount removable drive after formatting to ext

Tags: linux, formatting, mount

I'm trying to install Crouton on a USB Stick for Chrome OS.

> Procedure

First thing I did was unmounted:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
```

Then I formatted to ext:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
```

Then I try to mount again by running the command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1
```

> Error

`mount: can't find /dev/sda1 in /etc/fstab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what Linux flavour you're using.

Mount appeared to fail and looked in the fstab file (/etc/fstab ) for mounting options.

you could try.

```
~]# mkdir /mount/point
~]# mount -t ext4 /dev/device /mount/point
```

OR

To mount permanently add to fstab. Ref   [/etc/fstab overview](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38125/htg-explains-what-is-the-linux-fstab-and-how-does-it-work/)

All the best